Why do edges appear visible and misaligned in my skybox despite correct face assignments?
I am implementing a skybox in my 3D python project using six separate texture files for each face of the cube. The texture files are named according to their orientation:
nx: Negative X (left face)
px: Positive X (right face)
ny: Negative Y (bottom face)
py: Positive Y (top face)
nz: Negative Z (back face)
pz: Positive Z (front face)
I applied the textures to the corresponding cube faces, but the edges between the faces are clearly visible, and the overall alignment looks wrong.

I suspect either:
Some textures might be reversed, rotated, or flipped.
The UV mapping or face orientation of my cube might be incorrect.
Texture filtering or wrapping settings might be causing issues.
What I’ve tried:
Verified that each texture is mapped to the correct face based on the naming convention.
Manually inspected the textures for alignment but couldn’t determine if they are correctly oriented.
Observations:
The seams are visible and do not blend well between faces.
The textures do not appear to flow seamlessly across adjacent edges.
My Questions:
How can I determine if the issue is due to incorrect texture orientation (e.g., flipping or rotation)?
Are there techniques to debug and verify proper alignment of skybox textures?
Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
My Code File:
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from math import pi, sin, cos, sqrt

# Load textures
def load_texture(file_path, use_alpha=False):
    try:
        # Use convert_alpha() for images with transparency
        if use_alpha:
            texture_surface = pygame.image.load(file_path).convert_alpha()
            texture_data = pygame.image.tostring(texture_surface, "RGBA", True)
        else:
            texture_surface = pygame.image.load(file_path).convert()
            texture_data = pygame.image.tostring(texture_surface, "RGB", True)
        width, height = texture_surface.get_size()

        texture_id = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id)

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

        # Use GL_RGBA for textures with alpha
        if use_alpha:
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data)
        else:
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data)

        print(f"Texture loaded: {file_path}, ID: {texture_id}")
        return texture_id
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading texture {file_path}: {e}")
        return None

# File paths for textures
earth_day_map = "textures/8k_earth_daymap.jpg"
earth_night_map = "textures/8k_earth_nightmap.jpg"
clouds_map = "textures/output.png"

# Skybox texture file paths
skybox_faces = {
    'right':  'textures/px.png',  # Positive X
    'left':   'textures/nx.png',  # Negative X
    'top':    'textures/py.png',  # Positive Y
    'bottom': 'textures/ny.png',  # Negative Y
    'front':  'textures/pz.png',  # Positive Z
    'back':   'textures/nz.png',  # Negative Z
}

# Create sphere vertices, normals, texture coordinates, and indices
def create_sphere(radius, slices, stacks):
    vertices = []
    normals = []
    tex_coords = []
    indices = []

    for stack in range(stacks + 1):
        phi = pi / 2 - stack * pi / stacks
        y = radius * sin(phi)
        scale = radius * cos(phi)

        for slice_ in range(slices + 1):
            theta = slice_ * 2 * pi / slices
            x = scale * cos(theta)
            z = scale * sin(theta)

            # Vertex positions
            vertices.extend([x, y, z])

            # Normals (normalized vertex positions)
            length = sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)
            normals.extend([x / length, y / length, z / length])

            # Texture coordinates
            tex_coords.extend([slice_ / slices, 1 - stack / stacks])

    for stack in range(stacks):
        for slice_ in range(slices):
            first = stack * (slices + 1) + slice_
            second = first + slices + 1
            indices.extend([first, second, first + 1, second, second + 1, first + 1])

    return vertices, normals, tex_coords, indices

# Setup lighting
def setup_lighting():
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

    light_position = [1, 1, 1, 0]
    light_color = [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1]
    ambient_light = [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1]

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient_light)

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.0])
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0])
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 50.0)

# Main application
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    setup_lighting()

    # Load textures
    day_texture = load_texture(earth_day_map)
    night_texture = load_texture(earth_night_map)
    clouds_texture = load_texture(clouds_map, use_alpha=True)

    skybox_textures = {}
    for face, file in skybox_faces.items():
        skybox_textures[face] = load_texture(file)

    if day_texture is None or night_texture is None or clouds_texture is None:
        print("Failed to load textures.")
        return

    # Sphere data for Earth
    radius = 1.0
    slices = 64
    stacks = 64
    vertices, normals, tex_coords, indices = create_sphere(radius, slices, stacks)

    # Sphere data for clouds
    clouds_radius = 1.02  # Slightly larger than Earth's radius
    clouds_vertices, clouds_normals, clouds_tex_coords, _ = create_sphere(clouds_radius, slices, stacks)

    # Set up perspective and view matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 100)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    zoom = -5
    rotation_x, rotation_y = 0, 0
    current_texture = day_texture

    def render_skybox(size):
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)

        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, 0)
        glScalef(size, size, size)

        faces = [
            ('right',  [(1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, -1)]),
            ('left',   [(-1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1)]),
            ('top',    [(-1, 1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1)]),
            ('bottom', [(-1, -1, 1), (1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, -1)]),
            ('front',  [(-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, -1)]),
            ('back',   [(1, -1, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)]),
        ]

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

        for face_name, vertices in faces:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skybox_textures[face_name])
            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
            for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(vertices):
                s = i % 2
                t = (i // 2) % 2
                glTexCoord2f(s, t)
                glVertex3f(x, y, z)
            glEnd()

        glPopMatrix()

        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)

    def compute_zoom_step(zoom, min_zoom, max_zoom):
        zoom_range = max_zoom - min_zoom
        distance_to_limit = min(zoom - min_zoom, max_zoom - zoom)
        return (distance_to_limit / zoom_range) * 0.5

    min_zoom, max_zoom = -10, -1.2

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                step = compute_zoom_step(zoom, min_zoom, max_zoom)
                if event.button == 4:  # Scroll up
                    zoom = min(max_zoom, zoom + step)
                if event.button == 5:  # Scroll down
                    zoom = max(min_zoom, zoom - step)
            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:  # Left button pressed
                    dx, dy = event.rel
                    rotation_x += dy * 0.5
                    rotation_y += dx * 0.5
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_n:  # Press 'n' to toggle night texture
                    current_texture = night_texture if current_texture == day_texture else day_texture

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, zoom)
        glRotatef(rotation_x, 1, 0, 0)
        glRotatef(rotation_y, 0, 1, 0)

        # Render the skybox before other objects
        render_skybox(size=50)

        # --- Render Earth ---
        glPushMatrix()
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, current_texture)

        glDisable(GL_BLEND)         # Ensure blending is disabled
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)        # Enable depth writing

        # Enable and set pointers
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        # Convert lists to GLfloat arrays
        vertex_data = (GLfloat * len(vertices))(*vertices)
        normal_data = (GLfloat * len(normals))(*normals)
        texcoord_data = (GLfloat * len(tex_coords))(*tex_coords)
        index_data = (GLuint * len(indices))(*indices)

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex_data)
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normal_data)
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texcoord_data)

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, index_data)

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        glPopMatrix()

        # --- Render Clouds ---
        glPushMatrix()
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, clouds_texture)

        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)       # Disable depth writing

        if current_texture == day_texture:
            glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9)
        else:
            glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2)  # Set transparency

        # Enable and set pointers for clouds
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        clouds_vertex_data = (GLfloat * len(clouds_vertices))(*clouds_vertices)
        clouds_normal_data = (GLfloat * len(clouds_normals))(*clouds_normals)
        clouds_texcoord_data = (GLfloat * len(clouds_tex_coords))(*clouds_tex_coords)
        clouds_index_data = (GLuint * len(indices))(*indices)  # Use the same indices

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, clouds_vertex_data)
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, clouds_normal_data)
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, clouds_texcoord_data)

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, clouds_index_data)

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)        # Re-enable depth writing
        glDisable(GL_BLEND)

        glPopMatrix()

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Ps: If needed, I can provide the skybox images.
